# NSNumberFormatter for Currency

Tags: nsnumberformatter

I'm using NSNumberFormatter for currency formatting. I have explicitly mentioned the currency symbol, currency group separator, currency decimal separator. It is working as expected. But, when i change the region format to some specific region in device settings, It is not working and the formatting of the text is also getting affected. How to overcome with this ? I want the formatter to format based on the properties that i have set to it and not based on device level region settings.

Answer (score 2):

What region are you specifying that causes this behavior?

This code works for me, regardless of the region I set:

```
NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
nf.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
nf.currencySymbol = @"A";
nf.currencyDecimalSeparator = @"B";
nf.currencyGroupingSeparator = @"C";
label.text = [nf stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:65123.45]];
```